# Geometry Nodes - Sample unit scale

Tags: geometry-nodes, transforms

Pretty much as the title states, I would like to sample file unit scale inside geo nodes. This is to foolproof my node setup if shared with other users. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: Do you mean Scene - Units - Unit Scale?

Comment: Yes that's right, I would like to sample Scene Units Scale to accurately project object thickness regardless of scene units denomination used (1 or .01).

Comment: I don't know a way to do it in geometry nodes directly. But there is probably a way by using a script and maybe a way to pass it as a parameter to the node. Anyways, I don't think, that these options are what you are looking for, when you want to make it foolproof for your users.